# In Blender 2.8, can we create a "hidden" Vector input for a node group like that of a Texture node with Python?

Tags: python, shader-nodes

In Blender 2.8, ShaderNodeSockets don't have the hide_value function, so I can't create a Vector socket and then hide it. This makes me think there must be another type of Vector socket which does not display the input value channels because if I create a new Input socket by connecting the Vector input of a Texture node, I get the Vector socket with hidden inputs that I wanted.

Is there a specific type of Vector NodeSocket which does not display the input values?